# Need help to understanding CQRS architecture

Tags: cqrs

I try to under cqrs architecture style. I found sample image of cqrs architecture.

http://blog.trifork.com//wp-content/uploads/2010/01/cqrs_architecturehighlevel.png

If command handling is persisting data to database, why event handling update storage to?

Example:

If I have CreateUserCommand, where place the persistent, in command handling or event handling.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

From the diagram, it looks to me like a CQRS and event sourced architecture. This means that the domain model will generate events in response to commands. Unlike DTO or view models, you store them in an event store. The event store holds the state transitions for the domain but is not used for the front end. For the front end you need a read model. You generate a read model from the events. Hence the need for the event handlers to write to the database. Of course they are writing to the read model not the event store. I have a similar diagram with more detailed explanation at my blog. You can find the post here: [CQRS: A Step by Step Guide to The Flow of a Typical Application](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/02/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/). I hope you find the helpful.